# Grafana not updating dashboard panels

Tags: grafana

My Grafana Dashboard does't update the content of panels which calls some SQL-Database content. I set up the auto dashboard refresh time period for 1m. After 1m I see the refresh query but the content is not updated. For refreshing the content I have to press F5 in browser. How can I update the Content of each Panels or send automatically the refresh query?

Comment: What type of the panels are you expecting to be updated.

Comment: @JanGaraj 3 different Panels wich use data source like SQL-Server & JSON and SimpleJson